# How do I get rid of space between 2 views

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UITableView` with a `iAd Banner` right under it. I applied `constraints` to them:

**TableView**

[image]

**iAd Banner**

[image]

**Sometimes**, when I run the app, there's a space (the amount of the `banners` height) between the `tableView` and the `banner` after the `banner` loads. It's weird, because it only happens sometimes. I can't pinpoint when it happens and when it doesn't.

But when there is that space and I rotate the iPhone, I get the following message:

```
[4381:133861] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79039930 V:[UILabel:0x79039800'00:45'(57)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79036f30 V:[UIButton:0x79036d50'First'(60)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79035f80 V:[UIButton:0x79036620'second'(60)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79039ec0 V:|-(8)-[UILabel:0x79039800'00:45']   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79039d00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79039f80 V:[UILabel:0x79039800'00:45']-(8)-[UIButton:0x79036d50'First']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7903a070 V:[UIButton:0x79036d50'First']-(8)-[UIButton:0x79036620'second']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7903a0a0 V:[UIButton:0x79036620'second']-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79039d00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79038240 V:|-(0)-[ADDimmerView:0x7861e140]   (Names: '|':ADBannerView:0x79037290 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x790382b0 V:[ADDimmerView:0x7861e140]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':ADBannerView:0x79037290 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7903abb0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7903a1e0]-(0)-[UIView:0x79039d00]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7903ac40 V:[UIView:0x79039d00]-(8)-[UITableView:0x78c02a00]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7903aca0 ADBannerView:0x79037290.bottom == _UILayoutGuide:0x7903a730.top>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7903acd0 V:[UITableView:0x78c02a00]-(0)-[ADBannerView:0x79037290]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x790356e0 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7903a1e0(64)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x790357b0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x7903a1e0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x79039c40 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x79035920 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x7903a730(0)]>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x79035680 _UILayoutGuide:0x7903a730.bottom == UIView:0x79039c40.bottom>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79045280 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UIView:0x79039c40(270)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x79035f80 V:[UIButton:0x79036620'second'(60)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

How can I get rid of that space?

Here's my code:

```
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.bottomAddView?.hidden = false
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    self.bottomAddView?.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: Can you please add screenshot to have better idea of view and how you have set constraints. Please select all the views so constraint can be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to add a constraint to the iAd Banner for height and see if that fixes it.